# Show that $S$ has a compact closure in $C([0,1])$ with sup-norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, where $\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|f(x)|.$

Tags: real-analysis, arzela-ascoli

Let $S$ be the  set  of  all  functions $f$ that are  continuous on  $[0,1]$ and  differentiable  on  $(0,1)$ with  $\int_{0}^{1}|f^1|^2\,dm\leq1$.  Show that $S$ has  a  compact  closure  in  $C([0,1])$  with  sup-norm  $\|\cdot\|_\infty$,\ where  $\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{0\leq x\leq1}|f(x)|$.

My work-

I'm going to use the Arzela Ascoli theorem. What I need to prove here is,

1.uniformly bounded
2. Equicontnuity

For that, First I need to show the uniform boundedness.
let $f\in S$ then consider $|f(x)-f(0)|=|\int_{0}^{1}|f^1||\leq|\int_{0}^{1}|f|^2|$ by fundamental theorem of calculus and then applied Hölder's theorem.

then $|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(0)+f(0)|\leq|f(x)-f(0)|+|f(0)|\leq1+f(0)$. Here my concern is that $f(0)$ is not bounded for all $f$.

I'm sure there should be another way to solve this.

Comment: You can use italic letters without putting the text into math mode. It does not look good.

Comment: Is $f^1$ the derivative of $f$?

Comment: Even if $f^1$ means the derivative $f^{(1)}=f'$, it's still not correct that $\lvert f(x)-f(0)\rvert=\big\lvert\int_0^1\lvert f'\rvert\big\rvert$, but at least we have $\lvert f(x)-f(0)\rvert=\lvert\int_0^xf'\rvert\leq\int_0^x\lvert f'\rvert\leq\int_0^1\lvert f'\rvert=\big\lvert\int_0^1\lvert f'\rvert\big\rvert$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. If $f_n(x)=n$ for all $x$ then $(f_n)$ is  a sequence in $S$ which is not bounded.

Comment: If ‘$\int_{0}^{1}|f^1|\,dm\leq1$’ means $\lVert f'\rVert_1=\int\lvert f'\rvert\leq1$ (as was suggested in the comments), then these are in $S$; but if it means $\lVert f\rVert_1=\int\lvert f\rvert^1\leq1$ (which is what it literally says), then these are not in $S$ for $n>1$.

Comment: @TobyBartels OP has used  fact that  $f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^{x} f^{1} (t)dt$ so $f^{1}$ has to be the derivative.

Comment: I figured that's where that idea came from, but OP actually said that $f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^1|f^1(t)|dt$ (or at least that their absolute values are equal), and that's not true even if $f^1$ is the derivative. So I worry that OP is confused enough that they may not actually understand what $f^1$ means in wherever they found this question (or in whatever made them think of this question). Your answer may be right, but it may be irrelevant, and it's hard to tell from the OP which is the case. (I still voted it up, but it needs this note of caution IMO.)